# how to link to pages in the same directory using html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<header className="App-header">
        <div class ="Header" id="Welcome-Sign" />
          <h1> Welcome Sign-up Below </h1>

        <div class = "button" id = "btn">
          <a href='login.js'>Login</a>
          <a href='sign-up.js'>Sign Up</a>
        </div>
        <p>
          Get it to go Now
        </p>
      </header>
```

Above is the code I used for the a href to to link the home page to the sign-up.js page.

The sign-up.js file is in the same directory. any suggestions?

Comment: It isn’t clear what are you trying to do, .js files are javascript scripts, not pages, why do you have them in your navigation links?

Comment: why you need href? Do you want to render other html file or do you want to call methods?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `header` is not an HTML element, and `className` is not an attribute.

Comment: Thanks, this code is from react and im trying to render the .js file but I understand that it's a script. Should I just create a new HTML document and render that file instead?

Answer (score 1):

**Please Note this..**

if you use within same directory just give file name.

```
<a href="home.html">Home</a>
```

While within parent directory.

```
<a href="../home.html">Home</a>
```

While within sub directory.

```
<a href="sub/home.html">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your goal is, but if you use href, you can give it an id.
On your page, you simply put your target with the same id.

```
<a href="#newPlace">New Place</a>
.
.
.
<div id="newPlace"></div>
```

You won't need any js for that though.